# why `git log` doesn't find commit difference between local and remote branch?

Tags: git

```
$ git branch
* bugfix_1000
  master

$ git branch -vv
* bugfix_1000     1c51ced [origin/bugfix/fix1000: ahead 2] Merge branch 'master' into bugfix_1000
  master                433ecee [origin/master] TREIT-4160 | NCC - Follow Up Fixes

$ git log --oneline bugfix_1000..origin/bugfix/fix1000

$ git log --oneline bugfix_1000 -n 5
1c51ced Merge branch 'master' into bugfix_1000
2184619 xxxxx
7397a4e yyyyy

$ git log --oneline origin/bugfix/fix1000 -n 5
2184619 xxxxx
7397a4e yyyyy
```

Question> From `git branch -vv`, we can the bugfix_1000 is ahead of 2. Why `git log --oneline bugfix_1000..origin/bugfix/fix1000` doesn't display the different?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The revision range `bugfix_1000..origin/bugfix/fix1000` is empty, and therefore `git log bugfix_1000..origin/bugfix/fix1000` does not show anything. The revision range is empty because there is no commit that is in `origin/bugfix/fix1000` but not in `bugfix_1000`. A [revision range](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges) is always specified as `from..to` and not `to..from`. Only the changes in `to` but not in `from` are shown.

TL;DR: The revision range is inverted. You probably want to run `git log origin/bugfix/fix1000..bugfix_1000`.